# Adding a random background image in CSS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So I have a folder full of a bunch of gifs I want to use as the background for several elements on my page. I have a door animation on all of these elements and I want to have one of the random gifs display when the door is open. Previously I was just using one singluar image for all the elements like this:

HTML

```
<div class="door-position d1">
   <div class="door-back">
      <button class="door" data-date="11/01/2020">1</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.door-back {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-image: url("https://media4.giphy.com/media/8AdyAfsTMKi9QMaQ6n/giphy.gif");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a innerHTML for your css page or if I should be just plugging them directly into my HTML?
If that's the case, will my above style still impact that image? (height, width, size, etc.)

NOTE: the door transforms (opens) to reveal the image on the door-back property.

This was the JS I tried to impliment for what it's worth. This version I just tried having the image addresses in the JS file straight up:

HTML

```
<div class="door-position d1">
            <div class="door-back" >
              <button class="door" onClick="displayImg()" data-date="11/01/2020">1</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

JS

```
const doorBackImg = document.querySelectorAll(".door-back");
const imgArr = [
  "https://media0.giphy.com/media/r3jTnU6iEwpbO/200w.webp?cid=ecf05e47gf4jebecm9mhvyym9jgx01lmfl6xd3gesmmmhi6i&rid=200w.webp",
  "https://media4.giphy.com/media/phmwMLY1kkkMg/200w.webp?cid=ecf05e47gf4jebecm9mhvyym9jgx01lmfl6xd3gesmmmhi6i&rid=200w.webp",
  "https://media0.giphy.com/media/bnH2hkYp97rGM/200.webp?cid=ecf05e478lhuvbydmjxp51r50rufqjcxj2x1v0g6kug4o86s&rid=200.webp",
];

function displayImg() {
  let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArr.length);
  doorBackImg.innerHTML = `${imgArr[randNum]}`;
}
```

If you need any more code or information please let me know! I've not quite found what I'm looking for just yet and nothing I've tried has worked.

Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean with "if there is a innerHTML for your css page or if I should be just plugging them directly into my HTML"

Comment: Currently I have the image address in my CSS file, in the background-image property. Is there any way to access that background image property in CSS or should I be looking to just send the image to the HTML file instead?

Apologies for my lack of proper vernacular here; not sure how else to phrase it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can direclty manipulate the property. It's on `element.style.backgroundImage`. Do you mean that?

Comment: Check this out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp

Comment: Yes! That looks about right. 
So, from her I assume it's something like 
``` 
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://media0.giphy.com/media/r3jTnU6iEwpbO/200w.webp?cid=ecf05e47gf4jebecm9mhvyym9jgx01lmfl6xd3gesmmmhi6i&rid=200w.webp')";
}
```

Will that be manipulated by the setting I have on that class in CSS then? They seem do be doing most things inline, which I'd like to avoid if possible. 

Either way, I'll goof around with it some more, but thank you for the comments so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get you right, but here one of my solutions. It works for one door.

```js
const doorBackImg = document.querySelector("#door-back");
const imgArr = [
  "https://media0.giphy.com/media/r3jTnU6iEwpbO/200w.webp?cid=ecf05e47gf4jebecm9mhvyym9jgx01lmfl6xd3gesmmmhi6i&rid=200w.webp",
  "https://media4.giphy.com/media/phmwMLY1kkkMg/200w.webp?cid=ecf05e47gf4jebecm9mhvyym9jgx01lmfl6xd3gesmmmhi6i&rid=200w.webp",
  "https://media0.giphy.com/media/bnH2hkYp97rGM/200.webp?cid=ecf05e478lhuvbydmjxp51r50rufqjcxj2x1v0g6kug4o86s&rid=200.webp",
];

function displayImg() {
  let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArr.length);
  doorBackImg.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imgArr[randNum]})`;
}
```

```css
.door-back {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-image: url("https://media4.giphy.com/media/8AdyAfsTMKi9QMaQ6n/giphy.gif");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="door-position d1">
   <div id="door-back" class="door-back">
      <button onClick="displayImg()" class="door" data-date="11/01/2020">1</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! This is working pretty well!
I have 25 doors that are being opened based on a date prop I have in JS and these gifs are meant to be the background of each door. The idea is that they'd either populate on page load OR when the doorOpen event is triggered (I can figure that out). 

I just wasnt sure how to get all 25 doors to have a random image placed on them each time. 

The way you've written it though may just work! I'll just put all 25+ random gifs in an array in the JS; since I have no idea how to grab from my own documents yet

Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help you

Comment: Thanks! I tried this without making an ID for doorback since I wanted this to hit all the door elements (giving all a individual random bg image). 

It works PERFECTLY for the first door. The doorOpen event happens and the gif shows up right there behind it. However, if you click the second door, nothing populates after the doorOpen event and the first gif displayed then randomizes. 
Any idea how I can fix that and add this property to each door + not get rerandomized?

NOTE: I have pointer events set to "none", so that once the door is open, it is no longer interactable. It's so close!

Comment: It's hard to understand you without seeing the code. Could you, please, create the https://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Sure thing! Sorry there's a lot of code there and I only have the random image implimentation on the first two doors for the record. Also the JS is right at the top of the page as well!

I know it's spaghetti so hopefully with everything near the top, it should easy to find. Let me know if you get lost lol

https://jsfiddle.net/37wavfkL/

Comment: Okay, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5z0w371b/13/) I've edit some of your code. Firstly, now it's `document.querySelectorAll('.door-back')` because your code grab only one element. Secondly I've add a loop that is adding an onclick handler to every door. And thirdly I bring a little changes to your displayImg function

Comment: @LovelyAndy And the last thing. If you want to use a unique gif for every door, you should add `imgArr.splice(randNum, 1)` to your displayImg function.

Comment: This is fantastic! I haven't done too much with for loops (I guess I'll use forEach for most things), but this is neat to see how it all works. 
I have less than a week now for this to get done and this was the last big roadblock for me. Thanks again for all of your help; I really really appreciate it!

Comment: Should it just look like this then?

```
function displayImg(doorBackImg) {
  let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArr.length);
  imgArr.splice(randNum, 1);
  doorBackImg.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imgArr[randNum]})`;
}
```
Or does that splace need to be chained on something?

Comment: `function displayImg(doorBackImg) {
  let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArr.length);
  const imgUrl = imgArr.splice(randNum, 1);
  doorBackImg.style.backgroundImage = url(\`${imgUrl}\`);
}
`

Comment: Good luck with this project. I'm glad to hear that I've broke your last big roadblock. I would be thankful if you hit the 'best answer' and vote for my answers usefullness by hitting some up arrows. Thanks

Comment: Yeah of course! You really taught me a lot with this one (probably simple for you) fix! Great work and know you're a great teacher!

Comment: Thank you :) I'm appreciate this